# SWIFT - NSTimer, pass the user info

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nstimer

Im trying to pass the UIView() though the NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()

here is a code:

```
 _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval((Getsome("Adur") as! Double * 3.0), target: self, selector: "StartAnim", userInfo: ["vie" : bgview as UIView], repeats: true)


func StartAnim(timer: NSTimer)
{
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, UIView>
    GR(userInfo["vie"]!)
}
```

The NSTimer action is happening in another internal function

the GR(vie: UIVIew) is privat func

all those functions are in seperate UIVIewController extention file.

And the error im getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App.VC StartAnim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If StartAdmin takes a parameter, it should be called like:

```
StartAdmin:
```

Additionally, if you're using Swift 2.2, you should use the new #selector method:

```
#selector(self.StartAdmin(_:))
```

If the function is private, you will need to add

```
@objc
```

Before it's declaration as well, example

```
@objc private func someFunc(parameter: AnyObject) { }
```